# What is more preferrable way to say length is 1?

Tags: geometry, notation

I was wondering which of the following is more preferrable:

Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle with $AB=1$.

or

Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle with $|AB|=1$?

And should I use the character | or \mid when I write that formula in LaTeX?

Comment: You could also say: "Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle with sides of unit length."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, we say this: Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle with $|AB|=1$.

The character | or \mid is noth Okay.

Comment: I would say $AB$, not $|AB|$. But yes, both are OK.